# Ubuntu 12.04 Crashes on Boot After Installing NVIDIA Drivers

Tags: boot, nvidia

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. After installing Ubuntu and updating it without any problems, I installed the latest NVIDIA drivers for my graphics card. I restarted the computer and was taken to a black/blank screen. This is where I am stuck. I cannot do **anything**. That includes opening the terminal (or console... I'm not quite sure what the difference is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

- Boot your PC
- If GRUB doesn't show up on it's own:

  - While booting, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
- Enter Recovery mode of your Ubuntu via GRUB (advanced options)
- Select *root shell with networking* (`netroot`) and type the following command: `mount -o remount,rw /` This will give you rw-access to your FS.
- Remove installed graphics driver
- Type and execute `apt-get install nvidia-current`
- `reboot`

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I followed your instructions, but when I typed "dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-current," I received a message along the lines of "nvidia-current not installed." I decided to reboot anyway, but I still ran into the same crash issue. I restarted the computer again and tried to retrace your steps, but now I'm unable to enter the GRUB interface. Pressing "ctrl+alt+esc" just writes "^[^[" on the blank screen with the flashing underscore. If I press "ctrl+alt+esc" on the "Ubuntu 12.04" loading screen it adds "^[^[" after the four periods.

Comment: What nVidia driver are you using?

Comment: It was nVidia driver version 319. The card is a Geforce 9400gt if that helps.

Comment: Where did you get this driver from? Did you use `apt-get install nvidia-current`?

Comment: The driver management program "jockey-gtk" compiled a list of drivers and I chose the recommended one to install.

Comment: Try to reboot into recovery mode, but select "netroot" instead and use the command from my comment. That will install the nVidia driver provided in the official packages of Ubuntu. And for the future: Only use such 3rd party drivers if you can trust them or know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I was able to install the nVidia driver using `apt-get install nvidia-current`, but I am still running into the blank/black screen where I cannot input any commands. Should I try removing the current nVidia install?

Comment: You're talking about the one you installed before? Yes. And then `dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-current`

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: @the_Seppi could you write the answer on your answer?

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to me today using Kubuntu 14.04 after installing the latest nvidia driver.

To solve it, simply access via recovery mode and get into command prompt. Then run the following commands:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Then, reboot back to normal.

Comment: This solved it for me. I'd installed an nvidia driver using ubuntu's driver management gui. Removing all nvidia packages reverts the driver back to xorg, which is ubuntu's default.